# Alter view from columns in the View

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am using Oracle Database

I have View called `VW_StockOpname`

It has columns as follows :

```
S1_KL
S2_JB
S3_NB
S4_SB
```

It has data consists of numbers.

```
S1_KL | S2_JB | S3_NB | S4_SB
-----------------------------
1     | 0     | 1     | 1    
2     | 2     | 3     | 1
```

I would like to make another column so I can be easier to see the whole Code values

```
ASSETCODE 
---------
1-0-1-1
2-2-3-1
```

I intended to use this following code :

```
SELECT (ASSET_CODE AS (S1_KL ||'-'|| S2_JB ||'-'|| S3_NB ||'-'|| S4_SB)) 
FROM VW_STOCKOPNAME
```

to be added to `VW_STOCKOPNAME`

but how can I do it? as long as I know, View can't be altered.

Meanwhile, each of the column in the view comes from different table.

Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: `"VIEW can't be altered"` ?? [`CREATE OR REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm)

Comment: Script out the view, add the column, alter the view with the new definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as long as I know, View can't be altered.

Use **[CREATE OR REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm)**:

> Specify **OR REPLACE** to re-create the view if it already exists. You
>   can use this clause to change the definition of an existing view
>   without dropping, re-creating, and regranting object privileges
>   previously granted on it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_StockOpname
AS
SELECT ...
```